# How to make specific sides of rectangle to be resizable?

Tags: javascript, raphael, graphiti-js

I want to make few or single side of rectangle to be resizable in Graphiti.
If anybody has any idea then please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the version 1.0.0 you can override the **Figure.showResizeHandles** method. See the HorizontalBus figure for an example

```
/**
 * @method
 * Callback to update the visibility of the resize handles
 * 
 * @param {graphiti.Canvas} canvas
 * @param {graphiti.ResizeHandle} resizeHandle1 topLeft resize handle
 * @param {graphiti.ResizeHandle} resizeHandle2 topCenter resize handle
 * @param {graphiti.ResizeHandle} resizeHandle3 topRight resize handle
 * @param {graphiti.ResizeHandle} resizeHandle4 rightMiddle resize handle
 * @param {graphiti.ResizeHandle} resizeHandle5 bottomRight resize handle
 * @param {graphiti.ResizeHandle} resizeHandle6 bottomCenter resize handle
 * @param {graphiti.ResizeHandle} resizeHandle7 bottomLeft resize handle
 * @param {graphiti.ResizeHandle} resizeHandle8 leftMiddle resize handle
 * @template
 */
 showResizeHandles: function(canvas, resizeHandle1, resizeHandle2, resizeHandle3, resizeHandle4, resizeHandle5, resizeHandle6, resizeHandle7, resizeHandle8)
 {
    resizeHandle4.setDimension(resizeHandle4.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    resizeHandle8.setDimension(resizeHandle4.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

    this._super(canvas, resizeHandle1, resizeHandle2, resizeHandle3, resizeHandle4, resizeHandle5, resizeHandle6, resizeHandle7, resizeHandle8);

    resizeHandle1.hide();
    resizeHandle2.hide();
    resizeHandle3.hide();
    resizeHandle5.hide();
    resizeHandle6.hide();
    resizeHandle7.hide();
 },
```

This creates two resize handles on the right and left with the full height of the parent
figure.

Release 1.0.0 will be released at Sept. 17th

Comment: Thank you so much.I will be looking forward for the next release.It will be very helpful:)

Comment: Hi Andreas, In the above scenerio the resize handle pins will disappear from canvas. Can it be possible to show resize handle but not let them resize the figure? thanks